# Bootstrap modal window causes updatepanel to reload entire page

Tags: jquery, .net, updatepanel, bootstrap-modal

When I click the Linkbutton2 the entire page is reloaded. However if I simply remove the id="addLineModal" div but keep its contents intact, when I then click the Linkbutton2, the updatepanel works properly. Any ideas why a modal would break the updatepanel? Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="PriceAndLeadTimeRequest.aspx.vb" Inherits="PriceAndLeadTimeRequest" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="./MasterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <asp:LinkButton ID="OpenTheModal" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" Style="margin-top: 7px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addLineModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Line Item</asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpAddLineModal" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
           <div class="modal inmodal fade" id="addLineModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group" runat="server" id="divCollection">
                                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Press:</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-9">

                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <!-- Mainly scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
    <script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Jquery Validate -->
    <script src="js/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong. I will post the answer here as I couldn't find anything else out there on Google on this issue. Here were the problems:

1. The slimscroll file was the main culprit in causing the updatepanel to do a full page postback. I commented it out.
2. The other reason why the updatepanel was doing a full page postback, in addition to the slimscroll file, was because in the masterpage, I have ClientIDMode="Static". I had to set the dropdown to ClientIDMode="AutoID"
3. The last thing I had to do, in order to avoid the modal from disappearing, I had to move the updatepanel inside the modal-content div instead of containing the whole modal in the updatepanel.

Hope this prevents someone else out there from losing their minds like I almost did! :)

Comment: A second UpdatePanel worked for me and saved a big time waste. Still doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're still using the UpdatePanel or RadAjaxPanel (by Telerik) in 2022 like some of us, and encounter this issue; The button that triggers the postback should have ClientIDMode either not set, or set to Auto. Setting it to Static causes the full postback.